# Symbolizing only and all other in first-order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm having trouble symbolizing something like "Only cats play with all other cats" or "Only cats play with other cats" in first-order logic. I understand how to symbolize "only" and how to symbolize "other" but I'm not sure how to combine the two in this situation. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "Cats play with cats, and if something is not a cat, then that something does not play with cats".

Comment: Makes sense. Dogs would not play with all *other cats* ... simply because a dog is not a cat :P   And yes, that seems like a stupid remark .. but I am really wondering if you need to represent the suggestion that the thing we're talking about something that already has to be a cat in order for it to play with all other cats

Answer (score 1):

Let $C(x)$ denote "x is a cat" and $P(x,y)$ denote "x plays with y". Then:

-"Only cats play with all other cats" translates to:
$\forall x (\forall y ((x \neq y \land C(y)) \implies P(x,y)) \implies C(x))$

This says that given x, if for all different y which are cats, x plays with y, then x is a cat. Equivalently, if something plays with all other things that are cats, then that something is a cat.

-"Only cats play with other cats" translates to:
$\forall x (\exists y (x \neq y \land C(y) \land P(x,y)) \implies C(x))$

Again, this says that given x, if there exists some y different from x, which is a cat, and s.t. x plays with y, then x is a cat. Equivalently, if something plays with something different which is a cat, then that something is a cat itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the explanation really helps!